# android how to change the app_name dynamically

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the app_name value in String.xml?
not just setTitle();

I know there is a difference of languages may have mutiple xml files
but i still want to change the

```
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
```

to

```
<string name="app_name">Good</string>
```

Is there any way to handle this?
thank you

Comment: Why?  I can't think of a single use for this.  Where you would read the value into your code, just use another value.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: yes,everyone,it's hard to do this.i can only hide the icon in the app list.and handle with the short-cut.may used for some usrs want to change the name of the application,maybe the name leak the securty infomation.thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ahmad said, there is no way to do this. But just wanted to point out for you that the `res` folder is a `read-only`, so you can't write anything to this programmatically like you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would just to set a variable to equal your app_name string. And then have the ActionBar or whereever you plan on using the app_name string, just replace it with the 
variable you defined before.

Then you can change it at will. Just note that if this is for the actionbar you'll have to make sure to update the action bar after the variable changes.